How to resolve resource linking error in Android Studio?
installed android studio jellyfish and now I'm getting a linking error any help resolving the issue is much appreciated.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="103dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="272dp"
                    android:text="Welcome"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:text="Henry Barr"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_off"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
                    android:layout_width="264dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/weedsearchicon"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Search for anything.."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_Dark">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="402dp"
                android:layout_height="164dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mainlogo"
                tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Discount 10%~Off Hash"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/purple_background"
                android:text="Buy Now"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView4" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:text="Categories"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/cannabisicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Cannabis Strains"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="98dp"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/vapeicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Vapes and Accesories"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="98dp"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/bongicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Glass Pipes and Bongs"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="99dp"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/medicineicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Concentrates and Edibles"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Popular Product"
                android:textColor="black"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="See All"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/PopularView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipPadding="false"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/scrollView2"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" >
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:layout_margin="32dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp">

            </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



and here aree the errors I am receiving.
Task has failed previously.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':app:processDebugResources'.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows Daemon #0: starting
Android resource linking failed:
process = AAPT2 aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows Daemon #0:
command = C:\Users\Student.android\caches\transforms-4\92c032a1373051960c5792c1984038ab\transformed\aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows\aapt2.exe link -I
C:\Users\Student\androidsdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar
--manifest
C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifestForPackage\AndroidManifest.xml
-o
C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_
-R
@C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt
--auto-add-overlay
--custom-package
com.example.retailapplicationpt2
-0
apk
--output-text-symbols
C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\processDebugResources\R.txt
--no-version-vectors
--proguard-minimal-keep-rules
--no-proguard-location-reference
--emit-ids
C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\build\intermediates\stable_resource_ids_file\debug\processDebugResources\stableIds.txt
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":275}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:276: AAPT: error: 'black' is incompatible with attribute textColor (attr) reference|color.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":292}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:293: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipPadding not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AAPT2 aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows Daemon #0: shutdown

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:276: AAPT: error: 'black' is incompatible with attribute textColor (attr) reference|color.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 9s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date
Watched directory hierarchies: [C:\Users\Student\AndroidStudioProjects\RetailApplicationpt2]

I tried changing to the correct path in the sdk manager which resolved some of my issues just these left.I think now its using a wrong path still maybe.
